# Server B handling add_image_size() differently than Server A

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, cropping

I'm curious what dependencies `add_image_size()` has because I just copied a theme over to a new server and began adding thumbnails to custom post types only to find out that my request for hard-cropping is being ignored, and the images are kept proportional.

**functions.php**

```
...
set_post_thumbnail_size( 80, 80, true );
add_image_size( 'micro', 32, 32, true);
add_image_size( 'featured', 340, 225, true );
add_image_size( 'videowide', 460, 225, true );
...
```

On my local server (WAMP Server on Windows Vista) the `true` is respected, and the images are cropped in such a way that extra pixels are lost - edges aren't respected. On my live server (CloudLinux Server 5.5 x64), the images are kept proportional.

Is there some gdlibrary dependencies or something I am needing to change on the live server to get the expected results?

Comment: What versions of everything (PHP, Apache, etc) are they each running?

Comment: Both are running PHP 5.2.9 and Apache 2.2.

Comment: Is Apache loading with all the same extensions (and same versions of extensions) in both environments?

Comment: PHP Extensions are important here. Please list those for the two systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular issue was caused by an environment missing [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). After installing GD on the server, the issue was resolved. Of course you will need to go back and re-submit your thumbnails to have correct cropping, or use a plugin to retroactively recreate your thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminded me of a time when I was playing with the Wordpress 3.0 beta and ran into a similar issue. Not sure if this will help you or not, but I stumbled across this post in the [Wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_new_image-hard-crop-not-working?replies=5).

> Hi guys.
>
> I´ve spent a lot of my day looking for
>   a solution for this issue and here is
>   the solution, in front of my eyes!
>   Thanks to stylishbeachbum and Alex
>   Mansfield. Yeah, the issue depends of
>   the server. I´m using apache/php/mysql
>   on Windows XP and the php_hd2
>   extension wasn´t enabled.
>
> I´ve enabled that and now is working.
>
> Thank you guys.

I'd love to know if this is the case. I had a few experiments in my Wordpress lab using custom image sizes, but abandoned my tinkering when I mas met with similar oddities.